# Hide Question for a specific user

Tags: feature-request, questions, chat

Is there any way to hide a question for a specific user ?

I love stackoverflow and I am using it since 3 years now. I am mostly a questioner. 
Since about a month when I ask a question I get a very fast response (comment) by always the same user. Mostly its a theoretical complex answer and it is the starting point of a longer chat, which is missleading. I also observed, when the chat has started, then I got no answer anymore by users who probably would have a good solution. (I realized that, by asking in a different way with other tags, which seems to be the trigger for the specific user and I got good answers from other users)

How can I prevent this without displeasing the user ?

Comment: Side note - good distinctive user name can help - generally all userXXXX look identical, so particular person you are talking about  will have much easier time to recognize and ignore you (which probably make that person life easier as they is  clearly frequent visitor of the tag as evident by gold badge)

Comment: Thats a good point. I will rename my user. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is this about me? It's about me, isn't it. It's about me.

Comment: No its not about you. I don't know you :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to hide a question from a user, and there are many, many good reasons why there shouldn't be.

What you can do:

- Take the user seriously and consider the advice they're giving for a moment instead of dismissing it as "theoretical". If the user  in question is [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924220/how-to-emulate-a-real-external-sd-update-removable-storage-card-in-android-em#comment47972535_29924220), I can't judge the content of the discussion but they appear to have a lot of experience in that tag,  maybe they have a point and it's you who doesn't want to listen?
- If you still disagree with them, point out politely in a comment that their approach doesn't work for you, and explain clearly why.
- If the situation still doesn't get resolved, you could go to the tag's chat room and ask the community for help - is the user being obnoxious, or do they have a point? Perhaps they have some other kind of input, perhaps on how to state your questions differently?
- If the tone is really, really rude - I don't see that being the case here, mind - you can always flag one of your posts for moderator attention, explain what's happening, and ask for help. But for that, there'd have to be a serious problem - and a user just commenting on a lot of your questions doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. It is exactly that user. The tone is not rude and I guess the user wants to help. In the other hand I guess the User looks answering as a sport. ( first wins :-)). I guess I will rename my user account, as Alexei suggested, to be more recognizable and hope that the user will recognize me again and probably doesn't answer that fast :-)

Comment: Would it be rude, asking the user , if he could probably not answering as the first for my questions ?

Comment: You can could try and talk to them and explain your situation, but it takes a *lot* of finesse to do in a way that doesn't put the other user off.